# Error with Kendo for ASP MVC doesn't work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

I upgraded kendo UI 2014 to Kendo 2014.1.528 with MVC 3.Added kendo.Mvc dll to the all the projects and added kendo.web.min.js, kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js and style sheets. when ran the application no data is loaded into the grids, none of the exisiting functionality works. what are the other areas to check ? Do i need to upgrade all the other jquery files required for kendo UI.
using below jquery files

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/json2.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ba-postmessage.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout-2.0.0.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout.mapping.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ba-postmessage.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.blockUI.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.alerts.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.treeview.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.multiselect.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>
```

If this is the issue, how do i upgrade the Jquery files, is there any Nuget package to upgrade.

Comment: Are there any javascript errors?

Comment: Additional information: The controller for path '/Scripts/Kendo2014/jquery-1.9.1.js' could not be found or it does not implement IController. got this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i have done is just update the main jquery files. I believe kendo is not compatible with jquery 2.x, as I have tried with it and some controls fail. I use jquery 1.10.2 without issues. You may want to check if your jquery plugins work after the upgrade. You can use nuget to update, but use the Package Manager Console as you can select which version you want to install. Good luck